# Having trouble showing colours in flood fill game

Tags: java, arrays

My flood fill algorithm works, however, I cannot print the 6 main colors of my game. The Java function that allows me to print the 2-d array is in the class GameModel.java called toString():

```
import java.util.Random;

public class GameModel {


/**
 * predefined values to capture the color of a DotInfo
 */
public static final int COLOR_0           = 0;
public static final int COLOR_1           = 1;
public static final int COLOR_2           = 2;
public static final int COLOR_3           = 3;
public static final int COLOR_4           = 4;
public static final int COLOR_5           = 5;
public static final int NUMBER_OF_COLORS  = 6;

private static DotInfo[][] dots;
private int size;
private int currentColor;
private Random generator;
private int steps;

/**
 * Constructor to initialize the model to a given size of board.
 * 
 * @param size
 *            the size of the board
 */
public GameModel(int size) {
    this.size = size;
    dots = new DotInfo[size][size];
    generator = new Random();
}


/**
 * Resets the model to (re)start a game. The previous game (if there is one)
 * is cleared up . 
 */
public void reset(){
    generator = new Random();
    int color = 0;
    for (int j=0;j<size;j++) {
        for (int i=0;i<size;i++) {
            dots[j][i] = new DotInfo(i, j, generator.nextInt(NUMBER_OF_COLORS)+1);
        }
    }
}


/**
 * Getter method for the size of the game
 * 
 * @return the value of the attribute sizeOfGame
 */   
public int getSize(){
    return size;
}

/**
 * returns the current color  of a given dot in the game
 * 
 * @param i
 *            the x coordinate of the dot
 * @param j
 *            the y coordinate of the dot
 * @return the status of the dot at location (i,j)
 */   
public int getColor(int i, int j){
    return dots[j][i].getColor();
}

/**
 * returns true is the dot is captured, false otherwise
* 
 * @param i
 *            the x coordinate of the dot
 * @param j
 *            the y coordinate of the dot
 * @return the status of the dot at location (i,j)
 */   
public boolean isCaptured(int i, int j){
    return dots[j][i].isCaptured();
}

/**
 * Sets the status of the dot at coordinate (i,j) to captured
 * 
 * @param i
 *            the x coordinate of the dot
 * @param j
 *            the y coordinate of the dot
 */   
public void capture(int i, int j){
    dots[j][i] = new DotInfo(i, j, currentColor);
    dots[j][i].setCaptured(true);
}


/**
 * Getter method for the current number of steps
 * 
 * @return the current number of steps
 */   
public int getNumberOfSteps(){
    return steps;
}

/**
 * Setter method for currentSelectedColor
 * 
 * @param val
 *            the new value for currentSelectedColor
*/   
public void setCurrentSelectedColor(int val) {
    currentColor = val;
}

/**
 * Getter method for currentSelectedColor
 * 
 * @return currentSelectedColor
 */   
public int getCurrentSelectedColor() {
    return currentColor;
}


/**
 * Getter method for the model's dotInfo reference
 * at location (i,j)
 *
  * @param i
 *            the x coordinate of the dot
 * @param j
 *            the y coordinate of the dot
 *
 * @return model[i][j]
 */   
public DotInfo get(int i, int j) {
    return dots[j][i];
}


 /**
 * The metod <b>step</b> updates the number of steps. It must be called 
 * once the model has been updated after the payer selected a new color.
 */
 public void step(){
    steps++;
}

 /**
 * The metod <b>isFinished</b> returns true iff the game is finished, that
 * is, all the dats are captured.
 *
 * @return true if the game is finished, false otherwise
 */
public boolean isFinished(){
    boolean flag=true;
    for (int y=0;y<size;y++) {
        for (int x=0;x<size;x++) {
            if (dots[y][x].isCaptured()==false) {
                flag=false;
            }
        }
    }
    return flag;
}


 /**
 * Builds a String representation of the model
 *
 * @return String representation of the model
 */
public String toString(){
    String rep = "";
    for (int y=0;y<size;y++) {
        for (int x=0;x<size;x++) {
            rep += dots[y][x].getColor()+" ";
        }
        rep+="\n";
    }
    return rep;
}
```

}

The function where I am printing the array is in my GameController.java class with the call:

```
System.out.println(model)
```

.

```
import java.awt.*;

public class GameController /*implements ActionListener*/ {

private GameModel model;
private MyStack dots;
private int size;

/**
 * Constructor used for initializing the controller. It creates the game's view 
 * and the game's model instances
 * 
 * @param size
 *            the size of the board on which the game will be played
 */
public GameController(int size) {
    this.size = size;
    model = new GameModel(size);
    dots = new MyStack(size*size);
}

/**
 * resets the game
 */
public void reset(){
    model.reset();
    System.out.println(model);
}

/**
 * Callback used when the user clicks a button (reset or quit)
 *
 * @param e
 *            the ActionEvent
 */

/*public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

}*/

/**
 * <b>selectColor</b> is the method called when the user selects a new color.
 * If that color is not the currently selected one, then it applies the logic
 * of the game to capture possible locations. It then checks if the game
 * is finished, and if so, congratulates the player, showing the number of
 * moves, and gives two options: start a new game, or exit
 * @param color
 *            the newly selected color
 */
public void selectColor(int color){
    model.setCurrentSelectedColor(color);
    capturePointAtZero();
    sendCapturedToStack();
    equalityCheck(color);
    System.out.println(model);
}

private void capturePointAtZero() {
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    if (!model.isCaptured(x, y)) {
        model.capture(x, y);
    }
}

private void sendCapturedToStack() {
    for (int j=0;j<size;j++) {
        for (int i=0;i<size;i++) {
            if (model.isCaptured(i, j)) {
                model.capture(i,j);
                dots.push(model.get(i,j));
            }
        }
    }
}

private void equalityCheck(int newColor) {
    while (!dots.isEmpty()) {
        DotInfo dot = dots.pop();
        int x = dot.getX();
        int y = dot.getY();
        if (model.getColor(x,y+1)==newColor && !model.isCaptured(x,y+1)) {
            model.capture(x, y+1);
            dots.push(model.get(x,y+1));
        } if (model.getColor(x+1,y)==newColor && !model.isCaptured(x+1,y)) {
            model.capture(x+1, y);
            dots.push(model.get(x+1,y));
        } if (model.getColor(x,y-1)==newColor && !model.isCaptured(x,y-1)) {
            model.capture(x, y-1);
            dots.push(model.get(x,y-1));
        } if (model.getColor(x-1,y)==newColor && !model.isCaptured(x-1,y)) {
            model.capture(x-1, y);
            dots.push(model.get(x-1,y));
        }
    }
}
}
```

I am getting a IndexOutOfBoundsError when it approaches the end of the matrix.

If anyone could help that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many issues with the code to fix all of them. Still here a few the I noticed after a quick look:

1. Yes, the reason why the matrix is filled with 0 is that `currentColor` is 0 becuase you don't call `setCurrentSelectedColor`
2. A deeper issue is with logic. Let's look at `equalityCheck`

```java
        if (model.getColor(x, y + 1) == newColor && !model.isCaptured(x, y + 1))
        {
            model.capture(x, y + 1);
            dots.push(model.get(x, y + 1));
        }
```

This code means that dot at (x, y+1) will be updated only if it ***already*** has the `newColor`. Obviously you want it to be updated if it matches the "old color" i.e. color of the (0,0) but you don't even try to save that color in your `capturePointAtZero`!

3. Code such as

```java
    public void capture(int i, int j){
        for (int y=0;y<size;y++) {
            for (int x=0;x<size;x++) {
                if (x==i && y==j) {
                    dots[y][x] = new DotInfo(x, y, currentColor);
                    dots[y][x].setCaptured(true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

is rather inefficient. Why do you need loops if you still update only single  `DotInfo`? It can be simplified

```java
    public void capture(int i, int j){
        dots[j][i] = new DotInfo(i, j, currentColor);
        dots[j][i].setCaptured(true);
    }
```

Hope this helps.

**Update**

> I understand your comments but now I am getting an arrayIndexOutOfBounds whenever i call a number that is at the end of my Matrix.

Exception most probably happens because you don't validate your indices in the `equalityCheck`. You can add a method `isValidPosition` such as:

```java
public class GameModel
{

    ....

    public boolean isValidPosition(int x, int y)
    {
        return (x >= 0) && (x < size) && (y >= 0) && (y < size);
    }
}
```

and then

```java
private void equalityCheck(int newColor)
{
        ...
        if (model.isValidPosition(x, y+1) && model.getColor(x, y + 1) == newColor && !model.isCaptured(x, y + 1))
        {
            model.capture(x, y + 1);
            dots.push(model.get(x, y + 1));
        }
```

Note that it is important that `isValidPosition` is the first call in the compound `if`. This works because Java uses [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) for boolean statements.

You can hide `isValidPosition` inside your other methods in the `GameModel` and sometimes similar approach is the right thing to do. But I don't think this is the time because 1) it requires you to return some fake value from `getColor` (you now use 0 and I don't really like it) and 2) it hides from the reader the business-logic that the field is not unlimited.

Comment: I understand your comments but now I am getting an arrayIndexOutOfBounds whenever i call a number that is at the end of my Matrix.

Comment: This is the error                                                                                      Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
 at GameModel.getColor(GameModel.java:85)
 at GameController.equalityCheck(GameController.java:126)
 at GameController.selectColor(GameController.java:78)
 at FloodIt.main(FloodIt.java:35)

Comment: @GarretUlrich, see Update in my answer

Comment: How would i be able to capture the last element of each end then if i have a restriction?

Comment: I'm not sure I get your last question. Do you remember that an array of size `N` in Java is an array with indices `[0..(N-1)]`?

Comment: Yes I do however lets say I put a restriction on y i say that y!=size-1 it wont let me capture the last dot of the y column

Comment: Can I send some files to you @SergGr for you to debug?

Comment: As for debug sorry, SO and I personally don't provide such services :). Why to put restriction `y!=size-1`? Where I suggested anything like this? What single iteration of the loop in `equalityCheck` does? It says, I have a `dot`, let's get all its neighbors (usually 4) and check whether they have matching color and if so, let's add them to the stack for further processing. So what I suggest is that you need to fix "get all its neighbors" part to filter out **non-existing** neighbors and unless I'm mistaken this is exactly what my suggested in the Update code does

Comment: ok nvm sorry it works. Sorry for all the questions and thanks for all the help

Comment: @GarretUlrich If it helps, you might mark it as an answer

Comment: One last question sorry. I have updated my code to update the colours instead of putting them all to zero. But now instead of repeating a function and calling capture in sendCapturedToStack() how can i update the colours in my printed array?